# OpenGL different sized textures for the same framebuffer?

Tags: opengl

With OpenGL 3.3, is it allowed/okay to bind different sized textures to a frame buffer?

I.e.

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D, GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture200x200,0);
glViewport(0,0,200,200);
/*....
some time later 
... */
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D, GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture500x500,0);
glViewport(0,0,500,500);
```

I.e. `texture200x200` is a 200x200 sized texture, and `texture500x500` is 500x500, `fbo` is the same framebuffer each time.

My use case is a need to render to texture several times in a frame, and each of these textures is arbitrarily sized.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the [documentation](http://docs.gl/gl3/glFramebufferTexture) that suggests that you can't do this, and thus it should not cause a problem.